Stata biprobit - interpretation
Productivity and training are both binary variables. Suppose I am looking at the impact of training on whether individuals are productive or not by gender. I am using the distance to the training center as my instrumental variable (IV).
biprobit (productive = i.training i.training##i.male age i.gender wealth region) (training = distance age i.male wealth region) 

margins, at(training=(0 1) gender=(0 1)) predict(pmarg1) post

lincom _b[4._at] - _b[3._at]

This results in 0.02
categories:

3._at: training = 1, male = 0 (female with training)
4._at: training = 1, male = 1 (male with training)

I want to confirm if my interpretation of the lincom result is correct:
For those who received training, males are 2% more likely to be productive compared to females, and this difference is statistically significant.
Question 2:
I am not sure how to export my results. Could someone help me? Should I present only the lincom result, or should I also include the main table of coefficients? I couldnt find any papers displaying lincom results.
Suppose this is what my results for the main table look like (hypothetical):
                        | Coefficient    P>|z|    
------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
productive              |
           1.training   |   .1265    0.000  
           1.male       |   .188     0.000     
                        |
  training#male         |
                   1 1  |   -.03049  0.315   
                        |


Training has a positive effect on productivity overall.
Males are more likely to be productive than females.
Training does not have a significantly different effect on productivity for males versus females.

I should stick to lincom, right? and shouldn't interpret these?
Thank you so much!
